# Will there be any more seasons of "Prison Break"?

Tags: prison-break

I am a big fan of "Prison Break" and want Michael Scofield in action again. So please can anybody tell me, will I be able to see *the gang* again in action or not? Are there any plans for Season 5?

Comment: Michael had a son that was the whole point of the sara break out so what if they do it when he's older, and he wants to find out about his dad so he goes back to places to find out! Even sucre's daughter might be init when she grows up! Just saying

Comment: I loved prison break and yeah we didn't see him die. just because they were at his grave site doesn't mean that they didn't fake his death after breaking Sarah out. I think there should be more. I cant get enough of prison break.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aside from all the sources that may already corroborate that Prison Break has reached its ending in totality, e.g., IMDB/Wikipedia, it seems exceedingly unlikely that we would see Michael Scofield in action again, as the final episode of Prison break tells us:

> Michael hears of the bounty and devises plans for Sara's escape. In
>   the end, knowing that he is dying from a brain tumor, Michael
>   sacrifices himself for his brother, wife and child.
>   - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prison_Break#Season_4)

We don't see him die, but we do see Sara and his child at his gravestone, assuredly marking his demise.  When we also consider all the other loose ends tied up (other prisoners dying, Lincoln's absolution, deconstruction of 'The Company'), it lends for little further possible plot to continue on.

**Update**:  [Prison break going to be revived](http://www.ibtimes.com/prison-break-cast-officially-return-season-5-event-series-fox-2042416)

> One of these unanswered questions that likely immediately jumps to
>   mind is: [SPOILER ALERT] how in the world is Michael still alive? For
>   those that don’t know, “Prison Break” ended with a made for TV movie
>   in which the character sacrifices himself in order to save Lincoln,
>   Sarah (Sara Tancredi) and her unborn child. According to Deadline, the
>   10-episode event series revival will mostly ignore the events of this
>   finale, but will provide a “logical explanation” as to why the
>   character is alive. However, even if they explain how he survived his
>   death, writers also need to explain how he survived his terminal brain
>   tumor.

Comment: I assume you meant "exceedingly *un*likely". I'd fix it, but it doesn't meet SO's 6-character-minimum-per-edit policy. :)

Answer (score 6):

No. The the show is over and there are no plans for a season 5.

Comment: Any proofs for this claim?

Comment: @ChristianRau The shows last season was in 2009. imdb/wikipedia do not mentioning anything about new seasons. It is hard to prove a negative, but one can only assume there are no plans for more.

Comment: *"It is hard to prove a negative"* - True, yet as it stands your answer is a mere statement by you, on which we just have to rely, while the other answers at least present some reasonable arguments against a continuation. Even saying that there isn't any information anywhere about a new season would be more helpful than just *you* saying that the show is over.

Comment: @ChristianRau Thank you for the feedback. I will try and incorporate your advice into future answers.

Comment: But the show was great.

Answer (score 5):

"Prison Break", a television series on the Fox Network, ended its run in 2009, after 4 seasons. It concerned the breakout of a group of felons from a prison in Chicago, and the ensuing run to evade capture by the FBI and international agents. It starred: Wentworth Miller, who has gone on to other roles, though, decidedly few; Dominic Purcell who played his incarcerated brother, who has moved into motion pictures in a number of action thrillers, and guest television spots; Robert Knepper, who had a number of television projects since Prison Break, also a number of films; William Fichtner, who played the FBI agent in pursuit, has a currently-active television series "Crossing Lines", and a number of film roles since. Long story short, I don't think the show "Prison Break" is on anyone's radar for a comeback.

UPDATE: Today, 2015/01/18, it was revealed [that](http://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/prison-break-fox-would-love-to-revive-the-tv-show-35369/):

> ...“There is some speculation in the press about Prison Break, which honestly was slightly news to us…. Although we’ve made it clear over the years to the studio that we would bring Prison Break back in a heartbeat...It’s probably the perfect event series. If our old partners in that show are interested, that would be great. But at the moment, we have nothing else to report.”
>
> Purcell and Miller are currently recurring in their roles as villains Heat Wave and Captain Cold on The Flash on The CW. That series was renewed for a second season earlier this week.

Comment: From some sources I read, it stated *Prison Break* was only supposed to last for two seasons, but was found popular enough for Fox to continue the series for two more years. There was also litigation by a party who said Fox had stolen the idea for the series on life events which they brought forth in a story idea. This may have had an affect on series longevity, but nothing official to prove it.

Comment: Ohh!!! so this means we will not be able to see any more actions from Scofield.

Answer (score 3):

Submitting this as a NEW answer, since it clearly contradicts the first, based on information just received - after an additional 2 years.

According to information released August 6, 2015, Prison Break will be back for a season of 10 further episodes.

From [PopSugar](http://www.popsugar.com/entertainment/Prison-Break-Being-Rebooted-Fox-38042404):

> Cochairman Dana Walden added that the reboot will be "a bit of a sequel" that picks up with the characters several years after the events of the final season of the show. "It will address some questions that were set up at the end of the series," she said, and though she didn't confirm who besides Purcell and Miller would be back, she teased that "some of the iconic characters from that show will be back." Though there's no word on when it will come back, we do know the return is slated to be a 10-episode arc.

Answer (score 2):

Season 5 is scheduled to air on Tuesdays, starting April 4 this year. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prison_Break_%28season_5%29)